# Extracting details of the filters in an MS Project plan, specifically which fields are used

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am able to extract the details of groups, tables, views and custom fields from an MS Project plan.  I can get the name of the filters and if summary rows should be shown however I can't find anything about how to get the criteria or the fields which are used by the filters.

Does anyone have any tricks (or even code) to do this?  Or is this just a hole that MS have never filled and there is no way other than manually trawling through each filter and making a note of it?

Edited to add: if this is a case of manually documenting the criteria is there any way to spot the custom filters compared to the pre-configured ones which come with MSP?  Such filters will not be using custom fields and so can be eliminated from the manual process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is this just a hole that MS have never filled and there is no way other than manually trawling through each filter and making a note of it?

Yes, this is one of many holes in the api. And no, there is no 'built-in' flag.

Keep in mind users can change filters (and tables, views, etc) so that what is labeled "Milestones" in one file may not be the same in another.

Comment: thank you for the confirmation.  It is a shame that there doesn't appear to be a list anywhere I can find of the "standard" filters (which can be changed of course but often don't seem to be) which I could use as an initial filter.  I supose I could look at some sort of screen scrapper to run through all the filters but I KNOW that it will be faster to just to suck it up and do it manually :)